# Alignment in the Leftbar Environment. Is Rightbar possible?

Tags: spacing, indentation

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43255/indentation-in-leftbar-environment) question I asked about changing the indentation (on the left) in the `leftbar` environment. I've got things nicely lined up (with the bar outside of the text field), but there is a little bit of space on the right side that I'd like to remove. Also, how does one convert a *leftbar* into a *rightbar*?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\leftbarwidth}
\setlength{\leftbarwidth}{3pt}
\newlength{\leftbarsep}
\setlength{\leftbarsep}{10pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{% 
\def\FrameCommand 
{%

{\hspace{-7pt} \color{black} \vrule width 2pt}%
\hspace{0pt}%must no space.
\fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{white}%
}%
\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{5pt}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{leftbar}
\lipsum[3]
\end{leftbar}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: see [how-to-choose-which-sides-of-the-border-to-draw-in-a-framebox/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/how-to-choose-which-sides-of-the-border-to-draw-in-a-framebox/40315#40315) as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If using [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) instead of `framed` is an option, then you can easily control all the attributes of your frames; in particular, you can easily achieve a `righbar` style. In the following example I used `mdframed` features two define two new environments `rightbar` and `mdleftbar` and I also used your `leftbar` environment for comparison purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\leftbarwidth}
\setlength{\leftbarwidth}{3pt}
\newlength{\leftbarsep}
\setlength{\leftbarsep}{10pt}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{% 
\def\FrameCommand 
{%
{\hspace{-7pt} \color{black} \vrule width 2pt}%
\hspace{0pt}%must no space.
\fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{white}%
}%
\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{5pt}

\newmdenv[topline=false, leftline=false, bottomline=false,%
  linewidth=2pt, innerleftmargin=0pt, rightmargin=-4pt,%
  innerrightmargin=5pt, skipabove=8pt, skipbelow=8pt]{rightbar}

\newmdenv[topline=false, rightline=false, bottomline=false,%
  linewidth=2pt, innerrightmargin=0pt, leftmargin=-4pt,%
  innerleftmargin=5pt, skipabove=8pt, skipbelow=8pt]{mdleftbar}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{leftbar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{leftbar}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{mdleftbar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdleftbar}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{rightbar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{rightbar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are my hero :) It works great!
Thanks so much