# Frame text with pgfornament across multiple pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfornament

I'm trying to create an environment that will frame text using pgfornament, the goal is to have one ornament in each corner, and a longer ornament on each side.

The catch is that some of this framed text will be long enough to span multiple pages. In addition I have added twocolumn option to the document class, but I want the framed box to stretch across the entire page.

I've found something that almost does what I want, [Martin Scharrer's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21522/14278) puts a red box around text. If I combine his `tikzborder` with `strip` from the cuted package it works fine with the multicolumn environment. I was hoping someone could help me adapt `tikzborder` to let me use pgfornament instead of a simple line.

Comment: There are many more posts of this sort, e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52579/121799). And it would be helpful if you provide an example with all the ornaments in it that show what you already have achieved.

Comment: Do you mean the `breakable` option of the [tag:tcolorbox] package? Because that package allows you to customize the style freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with this code. This probably isn't the best solution, but it worked.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentsidemargin}{%
  \ifodd\zref@extract{textarea-\thetextarea}{abspage}%
    \oddsidemargin%
  \else%
    \evensidemargin%
  \fi%
}

\newcounter{textarea}
\newcommand{\settextarea}{%
   \stepcounter{textarea}%
   \zlabel{textarea-\thetextarea}%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Helper nodes
    \path (current page.north west) ++(\hoffset, -\voffset)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight]
        (pagearea) {};
    \path (pagearea.north west) ++(1in+\currentsidemargin,-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight]
        (textarea) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\tikzset{tikzborder/.style={line width=1mm,red,double=blue}}

\newcounter{tikzborder}
\newcounter{tikzborderpages}
\newenvironment{tikzborder}[1][]{%
    \medskip\par
    % Allow user to overwrite the used style locally
    \ifx&#1&\else
        \tikzset{tikzborder/.style={#1}}%
    \fi
    \settextarea
    \stepcounter{tikzborder}%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \coordinate (tikzborder-\thetikzborder);% Modified \tikzmark macro
    \zlabel{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}%
    % Test if end-label is at the same page and draw first half of border if not
    \ifnum\zref@extract{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}{abspage}=\zref@extract{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}{abspage} \else
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]



            \draw [tikzborder]
                let \p0 = (textarea.north west), \p1 = (tikzborder-\thetikzborder), \p2 = (textarea.south east) in
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\y2-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SW) {}
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NW) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NE) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\y2-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SE) {}
                ;

            \node (CNW) at (NW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
            \node (CNE)  at (NE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}}; 
            \node (CSW) at (SW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h,opacity=0,color=white]{61}}; 
            \node (CSE) at (SE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c,opacity=0,color=white]{61}};  

            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](NELineAnchor) at (CNE.south east){};
            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](SELineAnchor) at (CSE.east){};

            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](NWLineAnchor) at (CNW.south west){};
            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](SWLineAnchor) at (CSW.west){};

            \node [shift={(0mm,6mm)}] (NEHeadAnchor)  at (CNE.west){};
            \node [shift={(0mm,6mm)}] (NWHeadAnchor)  at (CNW.east){};

            \pgfornamenthline{NWHeadAnchor}{NEHeadAnchor}{north}{46}
           \pgfornamentvline{NWLineAnchor}{SWLineAnchor}{west}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NELineAnchor}{SELineAnchor}{east}{88} 


        \end{tikzpicture}%
    % If it spreads over more than two pages:
    \setcounter{tikzborderpages}{\numexpr-\zref@extract{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}{abspage}+\zref@extract{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}{abspage}}
    \ifnum\value{tikzborderpages}>1
        \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage}%
    \fi
    \fi
}{%
    \zlabel{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}%
    % Test if begin-label is at the same page and draw while border if so
    \ifnum\zref@extract{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}{abspage}=\zref@extract{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}{abspage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]


                            \draw [tikzborder]
                let \p0 = (textarea.north west), \p1 = (tikzborder-\thetikzborder), \p2 = (textarea.south east) in
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\y1+\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NW) {}
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SW) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SE) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\y1+\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NE) {}
                ;

            \node (CNW) at (NW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
            \node (CNE)  at (NE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}}; 
            \node (CSW) at (SW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}}; 
            \node (CSE) at (SE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};  

            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](NELineAnchor) at (CNE.south east){};
            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](SELineAnchor) at (CSE.north east){};

            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](NWLineAnchor) at (CNW.south west){};
            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](SWLineAnchor) at (CSW.north west){};

            \node[shift={(-12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SEFootAnchor)  at (CSE){};
            \node[shift={(12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SWFootAnchor)  at (CSW){};

            \node[shift={(-12mm,17mm)}] (NEHeadAnchor)  at (CNE){};
            \node[shift={(12mm,17mm)}] (NWHeadAnchor)  at (CNW){};

            \pgfornamenthline{NWHeadAnchor}{NEHeadAnchor}{north}{46}
            \pgfornamenthline{SWFootAnchor}{SEFootAnchor}{north}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NWLineAnchor}{SWLineAnchor}{west}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NELineAnchor}{SELineAnchor}{east}{88} 


        \end{tikzpicture}%
    % Otherwise draw second half of border
    \else
        \settextarea
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]


            \draw [tikzborder]
                let \p0 = (textarea.north west), \p1 = (tikzborder-\thetikzborder), \p2 = (textarea.south east) in
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\y0+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NW) {}
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SW) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SE) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\y0+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NE) {}
                ;

            \node (CNW) at (NW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,opacity=0,color=white]{61}};
            \node (CNE)  at (NE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v,opacity=0,color=white]{61}}; 
            \node (CSW) at (SW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}}; 
            \node (CSE) at (SE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};  %Keeping these for anchorage

            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](NELineAnchor) at (CNE.east){};
            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](SELineAnchor) at (CSE.north east){};

            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](NWLineAnchor) at (CNW.west){};
            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](SWLineAnchor) at (CSW.north west){};

            \node[shift={(-12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SEFootAnchor)  at (CSE){};
            \node[shift={(12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SWFootAnchor)  at (CSW){};

            \pgfornamenthline{SWFootAnchor}{SEFootAnchor}{north}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NWLineAnchor}{SWLineAnchor}{west}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NELineAnchor}{SELineAnchor}{east}{88} 
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi
    \par\medskip
}

\newcommand{\tikzborderpage}{%
  \settextarea
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \draw [tikzborder]
          ([shift={(-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth, \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.north west)
           --
          ([shift={(-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.south west)
          ;
      \draw [tikzborder]
          ([shift={( \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth, \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.north east)
           --
          ([shift={( \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.south east)
          ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \addtocounter{tikzborderpages}{-1}%
  \ifnum\value{tikzborderpages}>1
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage}%
  \fi
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}% Compensate for the generated extra line at begin of the page. No idea why exactly this happens. Also \baselineskip seems not to be 100% right.
}

\newenvironment{fancyframedtext}{\begin{strip}\\\\\\\begin{tikzborder}}{\end{tikzborder} \hfill\break\hfill\break\hfill\break\hfill\break \end{strip}}


\makeatother
```

Comment: Can you post an image of the result?

Comment: @Fritz Image added, as far as I could construct an MWE in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse-engineered into an MWE, such as it is.

Some manual adjustment of the spacing could be required in places, in `twocolumn` mode anyway.

two-page frame

[image: two]

one-page frame

[image: one]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{zref-abspos}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentsidemargin}{%
  \ifodd\zref@extract{textarea-\thetextarea}{abspage}%
    \oddsidemargin%
  \else%
    \evensidemargin%
  \fi%
}

\newcounter{textarea}
\newcommand{\settextarea}{%
   \stepcounter{textarea}%
   \zlabel{textarea-\thetextarea}%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Helper nodes
    \path (current page.north west) ++(\hoffset, -\voffset)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight]
        (pagearea) {};
    \path (pagearea.north west) ++(1in+\currentsidemargin,-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight]
        (textarea) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\tikzset{tikzborder/.style={line width=1mm,red,double=blue}}

\newcounter{tikzborder}
\newcounter{tikzborderpages}
\newenvironment{tikzborder}[1][]{%
    \medskip\par
    % Allow user to overwrite the used style locally
    \ifx&#1&\else
        \tikzset{tikzborder/.style={#1}}%
    \fi
    \settextarea
    \stepcounter{tikzborder}%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \coordinate (tikzborder-\thetikzborder);% Modified \tikzmark macro
    \zlabel{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}%
    % Test if end-label is at the same page and draw first half of border if not
    \ifnum\zref@extract{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}{abspage}=\zref@extract{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}{abspage} \else
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]



            \draw [tikzborder]
                let \p0 = (textarea.north west), \p1 = (tikzborder-\thetikzborder), \p2 = (textarea.south east) in
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\y2-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SW) {}
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NW) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NE) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\y2-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SE) {}
                ;

            \node (CNW) at (NW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
            \node (CNE)  at (NE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}}; 
            \node (CSW) at (SW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h,opacity=0,color=white]{61}}; 
            \node (CSE) at (SE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c,opacity=0,color=white]{61}};  

            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](NELineAnchor) at (CNE.south east){};
            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](SELineAnchor) at (CSE.east){};

            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](NWLineAnchor) at (CNW.south west){};
            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](SWLineAnchor) at (CSW.west){};

            \node [shift={(0mm,6mm)}] (NEHeadAnchor)  at (CNE.west){};
            \node [shift={(0mm,6mm)}] (NWHeadAnchor)  at (CNW.east){};

            \pgfornamenthline{NWHeadAnchor}{NEHeadAnchor}{north}{46}
           \pgfornamentvline{NWLineAnchor}{SWLineAnchor}{west}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NELineAnchor}{SELineAnchor}{east}{88} 


        \end{tikzpicture}%
    % If it spreads over more than two pages:
    \setcounter{tikzborderpages}{\numexpr-\zref@extract{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}{abspage}+\zref@extract{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}{abspage}}
    \ifnum\value{tikzborderpages}>1
        \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage}%
    \fi
    \fi
}{%
    \zlabel{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}%
    % Test if begin-label is at the same page and draw while border if so
    \ifnum\zref@extract{tikzborder-begin-\thetikzborder}{abspage}=\zref@extract{tikzborder-end-\thetikzborder}{abspage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]


                            \draw [tikzborder]
                let \p0 = (textarea.north west), \p1 = (tikzborder-\thetikzborder), \p2 = (textarea.south east) in
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\y1+\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NW) {}
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SW) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SE) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\y1+\ht\strutbox+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NE) {}
                ;

            \node (CNW) at (NW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
            \node (CNE)  at (NE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}}; 
            \node (CSW) at (SW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}}; 
            \node (CSE) at (SE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};  

            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](NELineAnchor) at (CNE.south east){};
            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](SELineAnchor) at (CSE.north east){};

            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](NWLineAnchor) at (CNW.south west){};
            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](SWLineAnchor) at (CSW.north west){};

            \node[shift={(-12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SEFootAnchor)  at (CSE){};
            \node[shift={(12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SWFootAnchor)  at (CSW){};

            \node[shift={(-12mm,17mm)}] (NEHeadAnchor)  at (CNE){};
            \node[shift={(12mm,17mm)}] (NWHeadAnchor)  at (CNW){};

            \pgfornamenthline{NWHeadAnchor}{NEHeadAnchor}{north}{46}
            \pgfornamenthline{SWFootAnchor}{SEFootAnchor}{north}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NWLineAnchor}{SWLineAnchor}{west}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NELineAnchor}{SELineAnchor}{east}{88} 


        \end{tikzpicture}%
    % Otherwise draw second half of border
    \else
        \settextarea
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]


            \draw [tikzborder]
                let \p0 = (textarea.north west), \p1 = (tikzborder-\thetikzborder), \p2 = (textarea.south east) in
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,\y0+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NW) {}
                node at (\x0-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SW) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp\strutbox-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth) (SE) {}
                node at (\x2+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,\y0+\fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth) (NE) {}
                ;

            \node (CNW) at (NW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,opacity=0,color=white]{61}};
            \node (CNE)  at (NE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v,opacity=0,color=white]{61}}; 
            \node (CSW) at (SW) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}}; 
            \node (CSE) at (SE) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};  %Keeping these for anchorage

            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](NELineAnchor) at (CNE.east){};
            \node [shift={(-3.75mm,0mm)}](SELineAnchor) at (CSE.north east){};

            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](NWLineAnchor) at (CNW.west){};
            \node [shift={(4mm,0mm)}](SWLineAnchor) at (CSW.north west){};

            \node[shift={(-12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SEFootAnchor)  at (CSE){};
            \node[shift={(12mm,-9.5mm)}] (SWFootAnchor)  at (CSW){};

            \pgfornamenthline{SWFootAnchor}{SEFootAnchor}{north}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NWLineAnchor}{SWLineAnchor}{west}{88}
            \pgfornamentvline{NELineAnchor}{SELineAnchor}{east}{88} 
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi
    \par\medskip
}

\newcommand{\tikzborderpage}{%
  \settextarea
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \draw [tikzborder]
          ([shift={(-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth, \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.north west)
           --
          ([shift={(-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth,-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.south west)
          ;
      \draw [tikzborder]
          ([shift={( \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth, \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.north east)
           --
          ([shift={( \fboxsep+.5\pgflinewidth,-\fboxsep-.5\pgflinewidth)}]textarea.south east)
          ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \addtocounter{tikzborderpages}{-1}%
  \ifnum\value{tikzborderpages}>1
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage}%
  \fi
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}% Compensate for the generated extra line at begin of the page. No idea why exactly this happens. Also \baselineskip seems not to be 100% right.
}

\newenvironment{fancyframedtext}{\begin{strip}\\\\\\\begin{tikzborder}}{\end{tikzborder} \hfill\break\hfill\break\hfill\break\hfill\break \end{strip}}


\makeatother

\twocolumn
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\begin{fancyframedtext}
\ \par\kant[1-3]
\end{fancyframedtext}
\kant[1]\kant[1]\kant[1]\kant[1]\kant[1]\kant[1]
\begin{fancyframedtext}
\kant[1]
\end{fancyframedtext}
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```