# Bulleted list with vertical lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, cv

I want to add different positions within a company in a similar fashion to what LinkedIn uses, i.e. the vertical line connecting the dots of the bullet list. How can this be done?

[image: Bulleted list with vertical line]

Edit: now with a minimal working example after doing [some research](https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/annotating-latex-lists-with-flowchart-symbols.html):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\linkedlist}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
    \node (#1) [gray,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\linkedlist{a}] test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. 
    \item[\linkedlist{b}] test
    \item[\linkedlist{c}] test
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[gray] ($(a)!0.1!(b)$) -- ($(a)!0.9!(b)$);
\draw[gray] ($(b)!0.2!(c)$) -- ($(b)!0.8!(c)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem currently is that I need to add the lines manually in a second overlay picture and that I specify the "gap" between the dot and the start/end of the line using a percentage instead of a fixed value (e.g. 2pt). This causes the gaps to be of different size depending on the length of the paragraph.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've added an MWE.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Final solution (edit3)

Now, the code should work with page breaks in lists as well. Hope you like it :) If anything is unclear or you want some explanation about parts, just let me know!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{mylist} % new counter for amount of lists
\newcounter{mycnt}[mylist] % create new item counter
\newcounter{mytmp}[mylist] % tmp counter needed for checking before/after current item

\newcommand{\drawoptionsconn}{gray, shorten <= .5mm, shorten >= .5mm, thick}
\newcommand{\drawoptionsshort}{gray, shorten <= .5mm, shorten >= -1mm, thick}

\newcommand{\myitem}{% Modified `\item` to update counter and save nodes
  \stepcounter{mycnt}%
  \item[\linkedlist{%
    i\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt}}]%
  \label{item-\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt}}%
  \ifnum\value{mycnt}>1%
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{item-\alph{mylist}\arabic{mytmp}}<\getpagerefnumber{item-\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt}}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\drawoptionsshort] (i\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt}) --
          ++(0,3mm) --
          (i\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt} |- current page text area.north);% draw short line
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \else%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\drawoptionsconn] (i\alph{mylist}\arabic{mytmp}) -- (i\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt});% draw the connecting lines
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{mytmp}{2}%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{item-\alph{mylist}\arabic{mytmp}}{}{% defined
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{item-\alph{mylist}\arabic{mytmp}}>\getpagerefnumber{item-\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt}}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
      \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\drawoptionsshort] (i\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt}) --
        ++(0,-3mm) --
        (i\alph{mylist}\arabic{mycnt} |- current page text area.south);% draw short line
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi%
  }%
  \addtocounter{mytmp}{-1}%
}

\newcommand{\linkedlist}[1]{
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
  \node (#1) [gray,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
% Create new `myitemize` environment to keep track of the counters
  \stepcounter{mylist}% increment list counter
  \begin{itemize}
}{\end{itemize}%
  }

\begin{document}

\rule[-32\baselineskip]{2pt}{32\baselineskip}
\begin{myitemize}
  \myitem test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph.
  \myitem test
  \myitem test
\end{myitemize}

And a new list:
\begin{myitemize}
\myitem test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph.
\myitem test
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: new MWE result]

---

**edit2:** I managed to solve the problems @Tom mentioned by using `\pgfmathsetmacro\result{int(\x-1)}` and `\result` rather than `\pgfmathparse{int(\x-1)}` and `\pgfmathresult`. It looks like tikz uses `\pgfmathparse` for internal calculations that crashed the code. Using a name for it (`\result`), solves this issue. Also, I used the easier `shorten` syntax by @Ignasi.

TL;DR: Now `thick` works as it should, as well as the other options.

**edit:** Made the code work with many lists on many pages.

I used a list counter `mylist` and iterate over each node to plot the connecting line in the end of the newly created environment `myitemize`. This supports multiple lists on multiple pages.

**Original solution:**
works as long as you have a single list. If you need multiple lists, page breaking, etc., you need to expand the code.

I used a new counter to name and save the nodes automatically and iterate over them in the end.

Comment: I want to replace the `\draw` command with the one provided by Ignasi but `\draw[gray, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (i\pgfmathresult) -- (i\x);` gives me a _dimension too large_ error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, simple adding `thick` to the draw options results in an error: _No shape named i0 is known_.

Comment: Hm, sorry @Tom - I don't know why, I'll investigate.

Comment: @Tom I fixed the issue =)

Comment: @marmot Have you read the edits? The new code works with as many pages and as many lists as you want, as long as there is no page break between two items in the same list. I currently have a solution that takes care of page breaks as well, but want to give it a final touch. I will post it soon.

Comment: @marmot No worries :-), I took care of page breaks now. I deleted the old codes and just left a (short) description of the old to reduce confusion.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52579/121799) might also be of interest here.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `shorten` option to fix a certain distance between node's border and end of line. There's no nees for `calc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\linkedlist}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
    \node (#1) [gray,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\linkedlist{a}] test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. 
    \item[\linkedlist{b}] test
    \item[\linkedlist{c}] test
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[gray, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (a)-- (b);
\draw[gray, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (b)-- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

If `itemize` list is replaced by an `enumerate` list, it's possible to declare a new `linkedlist` environment which does all the work and uses regular `\item`s.

It works with only for one level lists and it doesn't break between pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\linkeditem}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
  \node (#1) [gray,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newenvironment{linkedlist}{%
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\protect\linkeditem{\arabic{enumi}}}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
    \begin{enumerate}
}{ \end{enumerate} \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \ifnum\value{enumi}>1% Only if there are at least 2 bullet points
  \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] 
    in {2,...,\value{enumi}}{% iterate over them
    \draw[gray, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (\lastx) -- (\x);}% and draw the connecting lines
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{linkedlist}
  \item test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph. test with a very long paragraph.
  \item test
  \item test
\end{linkedlist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I once knew about this `shorten` command and was searching for it but could not find it. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Tom It appears in examples in `pgfmanual` but I could not find any comment about it. It seems it desappeared in some update.

Comment: Indeed I used to read through the pgfmanual a long time ago and I was pretty sure I encountered it there, but could not find it very quickly when searching for it to create my MWE.

Comment: @Tom I've updated my answer with a new `linkedlist` environment.