# Draw line with latex

Tags: draw

How draw line and string of characters in latex

I have this figure:
[image]

this my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\linkeditem}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
  \node (#1) [gray,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newenvironment{linkedlist}{%
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\protect\linkeditem{\arabic{enumi}}}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
    \begin{enumerate}
}{ \end{enumerate} \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \ifnum\value{enumi}>1% Only if there are at least 2 bullet points
  \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] 
    in {2,...,\value{enumi}}{% iterate over them
    \draw[gray, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (\lastx) -- (\x);}% and draw the connecting lines
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{linkedlist}
  \item tiempo presion
  \item ultimo keyPress
  \item tiempo realce
\end{linkedlist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The picture only appeals to you. Can you enlarge it a little bit?

Comment: `tikz` seems to be a good option. Maybe [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454758/146828) could help you get started.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is too broad to be answered with the available information. Please add a `MWE` to make it clearer.

Comment: @x-rw you have been in this site for quite sometime now and we all know that this is not a do-it-for-me site.

Comment: @x-rw: It is great that you have added an MWE. However, to make it even clearer, please improve the quality of your image! I personally can't get it.

Comment: @JouleV i edited my question, see please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={minimum width=2cm},
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0 with {\arrow{|}},
        mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{|}}
    }
]
\draw[fill=gray!10,rounded corners=3pt] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);
\node (kd) at (1,3.5) {keyDown};
\foreach \i in {3,2.5,1}
    \node (kp\i) at (1,\i) {keyPress};
\node (ku) at (1,.5) {keyUp};
\foreach \i in {1.5,1.75,2}
    \fill[black] (1,\i) circle (1pt);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (kd.east)--(kp1.east) node[midway,right] {tiempo de presion};
\draw[postaction={decorate},blue] (kp1.east)--(ku.east) node[midway,right,black] {tiempo de realce};
\node[minimum width=2.5cm] (uk) at (4.5,1.5) {ultimo keyPress};
\draw[->,red] (kp1.east)--(uk.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i get error ! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }. in this line \draw[->,red] (kp1.east)--(uk.west);

Comment: @x-rw So you are having language errors. In your document do you use `babel`?

Comment: yes i used babel \usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

Comment: @x-rw Read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166775/156344) for a solution!