# Multi-grouped bulleted list

Tags: lists

Is there any way to create a bulleted list with multiple vertical lines grouping list items like the below picture in LaTeX please?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX!

Comment: You may be interested in this page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454744/bulleted-list-with-vertical-lines?rq=1

Comment: I had seen that before, but I couldn't figure out any way to extend that to multiple columns like in the picture I had shown.